# Cannot Find Firefox Binary when running Selenium Grid2 on Amazon EC2

Tags: selenium-grid

I've setup my Amazon EC2 instance and I'm able to run my tests and connect successfully, however, I'm unable to run tests for FireFox.

I get the following error...

```
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable(Executable.java):53:in `<init>': Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

I've installed XVFB, FireFox, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to add FireFox location to PATH.